# Apache Commons Email install in Eclipse: cannot be resolved

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, apache-commons-email

I'm sorry, I do not have enough reputation to comment on [others posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117343/org-apache-can-not-be-resolved-java/8401094#8401094), so I have to ask a new Question.

I'm on ubuntu Linux 11.10, and I'm trying to install the [Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/download_email.cgi) in eclipse. But the only files I can download is tar.gz and .zip. These cannot be imported with the method described in the other thread, where you add external jars in the projects libraries. I tried to drag the "src" folder into my "src" folder in my project. That gives the error "... cannot be resolved" What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried that, and that doesn't work. As written, I can't import the src folder, and there is no .jar file included. Luckily @Gray came up with a solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just about all of the Apache commons code is also in the central Maven repository which has jar that are easy to import/use.

> http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-990531281

I just went to the search bar and looked for `apache commons email`:

> http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Capache%20commons%20email

Answer (score 0):

Extract either the tar.gz or the .zip file from the files listed under "Binaries", and these will contain the .jar file or files that you are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not find it in the tar.gz or .zip files.

Comment: Right on the link that you provided in your original question:  http://commons.apache.org/email/download_email.cgi